# Given variable $m$, how do I find zeros of a polynomial in terms of $m$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, summation, factoring

This is a summation question about a finite series with sum $m$. I'm trying to write a computer program that takes in a given integer $m$ (which represents the sum of a series) and outputs the number of terms — or in this case, cubes — that are in the series.

Here is the notation:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^3 = m$

I know that

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

so,

$m = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

How do I find the zeros in terms of $m$? or the formula for $n$ in terms of $m$? (i.e. $n =$ ???)

Comment: Make a loop that adds the numbers $1,2,3,...$ until you get $\sqrt{m}$. Then stop and return the last number added.

Comment: Take square root on both sides. Now you have a quadratic equation in $n$. Solve that using the normal quadratic formula (remember that $\sqrt m$ is part of the $c$ in $an^2 + bn + c = 0$)

Comment: When you are programming formulas are not always the best option. For example, you are not going to get a faster program by using the quadratic formula.

Comment: ugh that's what I was doing wrong...figured square root of n^4 to be n^3, but it's n^2. If I hadn't made that mistake I would have easily used @user463383 's solution

Comment: via @Arthur 's math

Answer (score 0):

from $$m=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$ from here we get
$$4m=n^2(n+1)^2$$ or
$$\sqrt{4m}=\pm n(n+1)$$
for $+$ we get
$$n^2+n-\sqrt{4m}$$
$$n_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{4m}}$$
can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you! My mistake was figuring sqrt(n^4) to be n^3. Haven't taken math in almost 15 years.